# What is a non-arithemetic law?

Tags: probability

We say that a law over $\mathbb R$ is not arithmetic if it support generate a dense sub-group of $\mathbb R$ ? Could someone give me a translation of this ? What is the support of a law ? What does mean "generate a dense sub-group of $\mathbb R$ ? Any example ?

Comment: what is the source of this citation?

Comment: @miracle173: Remark 3 page 4 of [this article](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1975__30_2_145_0.pdf) or page 18 of [this article](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00497150v1/document) (after Salomon theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of a law of a random variable $X$ is the set of all numbers $x$ for which, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have $\Pr(x-\varepsilon<X<x+\varepsilon) > 0.$ The support is in every case a closed set.

For a distribution with a density function, the support is the **closure of** the set of all points at which the density is positive. For a discrete distribution assigning positive probability to every rational number between $0$ and $1,$ then support is the closed interval $[0,1].$ For more frequently seen discrete distributions such as the Poisson or the binomial, the support is merely the set of values that the random variable can take.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what does mean "the support generate a dense sub group of $\mathbb R$". In what is this important ? (For example, under the formula (1.3) page 2 of [this paper](http://www-m14.ma.tum.de/fileadmin/w00biy/www/pdf/Preprints_Publikationen/singlesite.pdf). By the way, what mean $\log^+(\rho)$ in this paper ? (I know it's an other question, but if you see the paper, maybe you can answer ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user380364 : Two things are involved: the group generated by a set, and the concept of a set being dense in $\mathbb R.$ The real line $\mathbb R$ is a group under the operation of addition. I'm guessing that addition, and not multiplication or something else, is the operation the author has in mind. Are you familiar with the concept of a group, i.e. a set with a certain kind of binary operation? The group generated by a subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ would then be the smallest subgroup that includes $S.$ That is the same as the intersection of all subgroups that include $S. \qquad$

Comment: @user380364 : To say that a set $T$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ means that between any two members of $\mathbb R$ there is at least one member of $T. \qquad$